# Strange behaviour in l3keys

Tags: expl3, l3keys

Consider the following code which uses `\keys_set_known:nnN`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {empty_module} {}
\keys_define:nn {module1}
   {key1 .code:n = {\keys_set:nn {empty_module} {a_key}}}
\keys_set_known:nnN {module1} {key1} \l_tmpa_clist
\clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

When executing `\keys_set_known:nnN {module1} {key1} \l_tmpa_clist`, the key `key1` is found in `module1` and, then,
the corresponding code `\keys_set:nn {empty_module} {a_key}` is executed. However, there is no key `a_key` in `empty_module`
and I would expect an error. But, instead, the key `a_key` is transferred to `\l_tmpa_clist` as we can see with the
`clist_show:N`.

I would like to know whether this is a bug or the expected behaviour as suggested (maybe) by `interface3.pdf`:

> Use of `\keys_set_known:nnN` can be nested, with the correct residual *keyval list* returned at each stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be called *expected* behaviour, but it's how the function is implemented.

From `expl3-code.tex`, the definition of `\keys_set_known:nnN` is (plus wrapper code and a few more things):

```
\keys_set_known:nn {#2} {#3}
\tl_set:Nx #4 { \exp_not:o { \l__keys_unused_clist } }
```

where `#2` is the module, `#3` is the key-value list, and `#4` is the `tl var` to store the unused keys. The function is the same as `\keys_set_known:nn` but it saves the contents of `\l__keys_unused_clist` in `#4`. So let's go for `\keys_set_known:nn`.

The code for `\keys_set_known:nn` now does:

```
\bool_set_true:N \l__keys_only_known_bool
\keys_set:nn {#1} {#2}
\bool_set_false:N \l__keys_only_known_bool
```

which is basically `\keys_set:nn` with a different behaviour for unknown keys.

(somewhere in the code of `l3keys` you can see:

```
\bool_if:NTF \l__keys_only_known_bool
  { \__keys_store_unused: }
  {
    \cs_if_exist:cTF
      { \c__keys_inherit_root_tl \__keys_parent:o \l_keys_path_tl }
      { \__keys_execute_inherit: }
      { \__keys_execute_unknown: }
  }
```

which either stores the unknown key in `\l__keys_unused_clist` or tries to do another thing with the key, depending of the value of `\l__keys_only_known_bool`).

So, the bottom-line is: when you call `\keys_set_known:nnN` you temporarily disable the unknown key-checking code, so the error you expected to see doesn't appear. Instead, as an unknown key is found, the `\__keys_store_unused:` is called for `a_key` and it is stored in the unused list at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed in the development code: see https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/526. The next release will take place within a few days and will address this and other `l3keys` issues.